# Will the Windows Home Server 2011 Connector work with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-home-server

I know the Windows Home Server 2011 Connector works with Windows 8.1, however, I am not sure about how well it will work with Windows 10. Do you know if the WHS 2011 Connector work with Windows 10?

**Update:**
While I have had success with Windows 10 and the WHS2011 for awhile it seems recent windows 10 updates have caused me connectivity issues. My windows 10 **Pro** PCs seems to connect without issues, but my windows 10 **home** have had connection issues that I have still not resolved.

Comment: This seems easy enough to test yourself.  Install Windows 10 on a virtual machine and install the connector.  Even if it works today in the current preview build it might not work once Windows 10 is released.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, knowing Microsoft, if the connector works in 8.1 Update, it should work in Windows 10. I would however, like to caution you on WHS, as it is becoming very quickly depreciated, and you should consider Windows Server 2012 Essentials or, when Windows 10 is released, using Windows Server 2016.